# "RPC error, your account is locked" when I try to deploy the last version of parity-bridge

Tags: parity, nodes, rpc, connections

I have already success to deploy the last version of parity-bridge (last month), but today i have pull the last version of parity-bridge.

I have that on my terminal :

```
env RUST_LOG=info parity-bridge-deploy --config bridge_config.toml --database db.toml
INFO:parity_bridge_deploy: Parsing cli arguments
INFO:parity_bridge_deploy: Loading config
INFO:parity_bridge_deploy: Starting event loop
INFO:parity_bridge_deploy: Establishing HTTP connection to main "http://localhost:8542"
INFO:parity_bridge_deploy: Establishing HTTP connection to side "http://localhost:8540"
INFO:parity_bridge_deploy: Deploying MainBridge contract
INFO:bridge::deploy: sending MainBridge contract deployment transaction and waiting for 1 confirmations...
DeployMain: deployment transaction failed

Caused by:
RPC error: Error { code: ServerError(-32020), message: "Your account is locked. Unlock the account via CLI, personal_unlockAccount or use Trusted Signer.", data: Some(String("SStore(InvalidAccount)")) }
```

Here is the config of my node :

```
[parity]
chain = "./spec.json"
base_path = "/tmp/parity-dev"

[ipc]
disable = false
path = "$HOME/urp/node.ipc"
apis = ["web3", "eth", "pubsub", "net", "parity", "parity_pubsub", "parity_accounts", "traces", "rpc", "shh", "shh_pubsub"]

[rpc]
port = 8542
interface = "local"
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
cors = ["all"]
hosts = ["all"]

[ui]
port = 8182

[websockets]
origins = ["all"]
port = 8452
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]

[account]
unlock = [
 "0x005eb3d86d6c987860fbc95ab97da69ee6b6118e",
]
password = ["node1.pwds"]

[mining]
engine_signer = "0x005eb3d86d6c987860fbc95ab97da69ee6b6118e"
author = "0x005eb3d86d6c987860fbc95ab97da69ee6b6118e"
reseal_min_period = 0
min_gas_price = 0
```

Obviously in the file node1.pwds I have the password of the node.

I think the problem comes from the connexion rpc of my node, because before the update of parity-bridge I connected to the bridge thanks to the ipc connection which is not possible anymore. And now i use the rpc connexion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the only way i find is to use the first version of parity bridge ...